# CheckBox colour not changing

Tags: android, checkbox, colors, styles

I have a CheckBox and I don't know how to change its colours.
I tried creating a custom style in styles.xml and styles21.xml
I added there:

```
<style name="checkBoxStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white100</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white87</item>
</style>
```

then I added the style to my CheckBox, as:

```
@style/checkBoxStyle
```

No change in the colour. Its still black and I want it white.
Tried creating another checkbox, cuz I taught I might have messed the previous one. Same result.

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".InputTaskActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">

    </activity>
</application>
```

XML with the checkbox inside:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white100"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        style="@style/checkBoxStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When unchecked we have only box that I want to be white87, when checked I want the box and the tick inside it to be white100;

Comment: Check if my answer below helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the style attribute to theme as follows:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: It works! I accepted your answer. I have one more little problem. How do I change the color when the button is active (the checkbox is checked)?

Comment: @VladSkurtolov Updated the answer! Try that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create a new theme with the new accent color. Then you have to specify the newly created theme in the manifest for the activity your checkbox is located in.

Answer (score 0):

CheckBox style in res/values/styles

```
<style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorGreen</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorBlue</item>
</style>
```

res/values/colors.xml

```
<color name="colorBlue">#022ce6</color>
<color name="colorGreen">#02e602</color>
```

in your actvitiy XML file

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```